# Linux run application failing because of runtime directory error

Tags: linux

I am trying to start an application on a RHEL8 machine and I get this strange error when attempting to run it. I am not sure how to runtime directory got changed from 0 to 10049831. As you can see I am logged in as root so the runtime directory should be 0.
[image]

Two things of importance to note.

1. I am working on a RHEL8 machine that has a display connected so there should be no need for an X display.
2. Within the 10049831 directory there is a file with ??? permissions that I am unable to read write or execute even as root user.
   [image]

Not sure where to go from here as I have tried many methods of fixing this issue and nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the application is doing. Seems at least as if the application was trying to start a process as user 10049831, and that it is trying to connect to an X display ... ?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.